# (C#) Can I fill a column in a group of rows of a DataTable with a certain value, only if they meet a certain criteria, using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, foreach, datatable

Iterating through a group of DataRows and filling the DataColumn in question with the value is taking too much time.

I have a DataTable with various DataColumns, one of the particular columns is ("DieID", typeof(string).

I have an array `DataRow[] binningRows` of DataRows of this DataTable that have certain DieIDs in that column. This array is the result of a Table Filter Expression.

I have to fill a different column (not "DieID") of all of these DataRows in `binningRows` with the same value, but this takes a long time because of the number of tables and their number of DataRows. Is there a way to do this with LINQ instead of a for/foreach loop? Willing to sacrifice more readability

Currently I am doing this sequence: Get List of DieIDs from filter -> Use List of DieIDs to get array
`DataRows[] binningRows` with proper DieIDs -> Iterate through Array of `binningRows` and fill proper column with value.

Code Sample:

```cs
List<string> dieIDs = table.Select(filter)
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(x => x["DieID"].ToString())
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();

foreach (string die in dieIDs)
{
    DataRow[] binningRows = table.Select("DieID = '" + die + "'");
    if (binningRows.Length == 1)
    {
        binningRows[0][paramIndex] = int.Parse(binList.Key);
    }  
    //else handle duplicate error **Was ruled out as cause of slowing**
}
```

This is clearly inefficient even though it is only hitting each row once.

I am going to begin exploring default List values as an option. I am already filling other columns with defaults and adding row by row (a bit different requirements but it is much faster), but struggled with it initially here because of issues with ordering and the fact that `paramIndex` is different columns each time

Potentially I could do something like

```cs
Dictionary<string, List<string>> paramDefaults;

foreach (string param in paramNames)
{
    paramDefaults.Key = param;
    paramDefaults.Value.AddRange(Enumerable.Repeat(string.Join(",", DieID,binList.Key)), count).ToList();
}

// code
// code
// code

for (int i = 0; i < numDieTested; i++)
{
    wafer.Value.waferData.Tables["Binning"].Rows.Add(waferID[i], dieID[i], devices[i], 
        paramDefaults[param1].Value, paramDefaults[param2].Value, paramDefaults[param3].Value
    );
}
```

However, I dont think this will quite work due to `paramDefaults[param1].Value` correct? Anything close to this?

Comment: just give it a try

Comment: LINQ is not faster than a `for` loop - it is slower (if you are using the right `for` loop). Your code uses `foreach` over `dieIDs` and then filters `table` with `Select` expression - probably the slowest possible approach. Consider: for each `die` you are scanning over the entire table to find the matches when you only need the first one. Reverse it: `var newKey = Int32.Parse(binList.key); foreach (var r in table.Rows) if (dieIDs.Contains(r.Field<string>("DieID"))) r[paramIndex] = newKey;` (don't run `int.Parse()` in a loop for the same value.